# Why is PowerShell using certificates to verify scripts? Is it more dangerous then cmd/bat?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

This might be a stupid question but I'm wondering why can't I just run any PowerShell script (`ps1`) as I would run `bat` files?

Even if PS has some extra (in-secure) commands then I can always bypass security settings and run this from bat: `Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File .\do_whatever.ps1`. If I can easily trick users to run my unsigned scripts then what's the use of the concept of signing scripts?

Surely I'm missing some security concern... Right?

Comment: Yes,it works like that, but to correctly run it, specially remote, you need the proper credentials. That's the only security part I see.

Answer (score 0):

It's a fidelity check.

Think about the "Certificate Warnings" you see on HTTPS sites -- you *can* just 'next' past the warning, but the warning will alert you to something that is awry.

One of the useful things with signing is that you know if your script has been changed.  Consider this:

*You create a script to perform housekeeping ClearIISLogs.ps1 and set an elevated Scheduled Task to run it each day. (powershell.exe clearIISLogs.ps1)*

In this case, if a user with write access on ClearIISLogs.ps1 attempts to change the script, the scheduled task will fail to execute.  The script would need to be signed by a trusted publisher again, before execution is permitted.

If you were to configure the Scheduled Task to bypass the powershell security (-setexecuitionpolicy unrestricted), modified ClearIISLogs.PS1 would be executed without fuss...

Comment: Let's consider your scenario. OK, I wouldn't be able to easily change `clearIISLogs.ps1`. But if I have have access to `clearIISLogs.ps1` and have a code signing certificate I can still replace your `clearIISLogs.ps1` with whatever. You won't even notice.

Comment: @Nux - I believe this is only true if your code-signing certificate is trusted (i.e. from a trusted publisher / root CA).  If I am mistaken, and _any_ certificate signature is allowed, please let me know!